# Serilog - not working on Client

Tags: serilog

I am using Serilog successfully in a WCF Service and it is outputting to a log file C:\Servicelog.txt on the hosting server. I configured Serilog in the same way on the Client application that consumes the service. When I run the Client application in debug mode when logged on to the server then it successfully outputs to my client logfile C:\Clientlog.txt.

However when I call the client through the browser from my own PC I am getting no output. I thought that it should continue to write to C:\Clientlog.txt on the hosting server. Checked whether it was been written to C:\Clientlog.txt on my PC - but it isn't. Appreciate any advise on why the client logging works only when the application is run from the hosting server ?

Comment: Which (Windows) user account is the client WCF service running under? It will need administrator-level permissions to write to C:

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, that was the issue. Once I gave appropriate access I started seeing my logs. Thanks for your help